# Feign Client and Spring Boot ERROR with a list param with more than 1600 items

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to consume a service with OpenFeign, the method is GET and as argument I send a list of IDs to make a query in DynamoDB, everything works correctly when the list of IDs is small, but in a real case, if the list is very large, example 1600 items then the integration fails, the request never reaches the client instead the response is:

```
feign.FeignException$BadRequest: [400] during [GET] to [http://<host>:<port>/config?id=7479c3943b4e706759d668fe63c0dff5&id=796dfc42ff2bd9a30b3dd30d6a9ca2be&<multipleIDs...>] [MyClient#getInfoById(List)]: [<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;... (435 bytes)]
```

What is the correct integration to perform a query with many identifiers?

Comment: I was not able to get it working, so the only way for me was to change API to POST method and sent list of items inside the body of request.

Comment: Faced the same issue when the request param having a big list of data, Got 400 Bad request from the Core API, Moved the request param data to Request Body resolved the issue.

Comment: that's right, I had to do the same

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

I encountered a problem when making a GET request with a large list of IDs using OpenFeign. The request was failing, and I discovered that the issue was related to the large payload size.

**Solution:**

To resolve this issue, I switched to using a POST request for large payloads. Instead of sending the list of IDs as query parameters in the URL, I sent it in the request body as a JSON array. POST requests are more suitable for handling large payloads.

**Revised Approach:**

1. Change the request method to POST.
2. Construct the request body as a JSON array containing the list of IDs.
3. Update the server-side code to expect the list of IDs in the request body and process it accordingly.

This approach allowed me to successfully handle requests with a large number of IDs without encountering size-related issues.

I hope this helps anyone else facing a similar problem with large payloads in GET requests. If you have any questions or need further assistance, feel free to ask.